sum groupby and add or sub row before to groupby and add row after to groupby
I have a dataframe and  I would like to get summing values for every [group] with one row Values before ('subtract' & 'add') and one row after ('BEGUZE_UE') the group. (A group can contain different strings, UE_1 doesn't matter).
But I get some wrong results in 'm_days'. Thanks for any help.
DataFrame:
data = {'ATEXT': ['', 'CT', 'RT', '', '', '', '', 'CT', 'CT', 'CT', 'RT', '', '', '', 'CTS', 'CT',
              '', 'CT', 'RT', 'RT', 'RT', 'CT', '', 'CT', 'RT', 'RT', '', '', 'CT', '', ''], 
    'BEGUZ_UE': [11.00, 23.00, 33.00, 15.00, 12.75, 19.75, 14.75, 23.00, 24.00, 24.00, 33.00, 15.00, 14.25, 13.00,
                 23.00, 24.00, 11.00, 23.00, 33.00, 24.00, 24.00, 24.00, 6.00, 23.00, 33.00, 24.00, 10.68,
                 21.00, 23.00, 12.75, 13.00],
    'subtract': [00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 3.57, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.08, 00.00, 00.00,
                 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00,
                 6.08, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00], 
    'add': [3.92, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 4.95, 00.00, 2.95, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 2.62, 1.92, 00.00, 
            00.00, 3.92, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 12.00, 00.00, 00.00, 00.00, 2.95, 00.00, 00.00, 4.95,
            1.92],
    'UE_1': ['', '', '', '', 12.67, 24.7, 11.18, '', '', '', '', '', 14.17, 15.62, '', '',
             '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 23.95, '', '', 17.95]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
Used Code:
m = df['ATEXT'].eq("")
cond = (~m) & m.shift(-1)
df['UE_more_days'] = (df['BEGUZ_UE'].mask(m)
                      .groupby(m.cumsum()).cumsum()
                      .where(cond)
                     ).shift() # orginal ohne shift() hier
tmv = (df[['subtract', 'add']]
       .shift()
       .groupby(m.cumsum())
       .transform('max')
       .eval('add-subtract')
      )
df['m_days'] = (df.groupby(m[::-1].cumsum())['BEGUZ_UE']
                .transform('sum')
                .add(tmv)
                .where(cond)
                .shift()
               )

Result:
   ATEXT  BEGUZ_UE  subtract    add   UE_1  UE_more_days  m_days
0            11.00    [-0.00] [3.92]               NaN     NaN
1     CT    (23.00)    -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
2     RT    (33.00)    -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
3           [15.00]    -0.00   0.00             (56.0)  [(74.92)] ok
4            12.75     -0.00   4.95  12.67         NaN     NaN
5            19.75     -3.57   0.00   24.7         NaN     NaN
6            14.75    [-0.00] [2.95] 11.18         NaN     NaN
7     CT    (23.00)    -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
8     CT    (24.00)    -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
9     CT    (24.00)    -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
10    RT    (33.00)    -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
11          [15.00]    -0.08   0.00            (104.0) [(118.38)] shold be 121.95
12           14.25     -0.00   2.62  14.17         NaN     NaN
13           13.00     -0.00   1.92  15.62         NaN     NaN
14   CTS     23.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
15    CT     24.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
16           11.00     -0.00   3.92               47.0   60.62 should be 59.92
17    CT     23.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
18    RT     33.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
19    RT     24.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
20    RT     24.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
21    CT     24.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
22            6.00     -0.00  12.00              128.0  137.92 ok
23    CT     23.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
24    RT     33.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
25    RT     24.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
26           10.68     -0.00   2.95               80.0  102.68 ok
27           21.00     -6.08   0.00  23.95         NaN     NaN
28    CT     23.00     -0.00   0.00                NaN     NaN
29           12.75     -0.00   4.95               23.0   32.62 shold be 29.67
30           13.00     -0.00   1.92  17.95         NaN     NaN


my suggestion is you should have a clear description of what you are trying to do

Sums should be calculated for each group. In this example, there are 6 groups in 'ATEXT' (CT,RT etc. ). Sum in 'UE_more_days' for a group = all values ​​from ( ) // Sum in 'm_days' for a group = all values ​​from [ ] + ( ).
